# Dynamically set values of ArrayList to variables

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a program that has an `ArrayList<String> s`. Is there a way to get each value from the `ArrayList` and set them to separate variables? For example:

```
String s0 = s.get(0);
String s1 = s.get(1);
String s2 = s.get(2);
.
.
.
String sn = s.get(n);
```

I will know what 'n' is but it will change based on user input. I just don't know how to/if I can dynamically create variables based on some number n. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How would you reference a dynamically created variable?  It wouldn't exist at compile time.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just get the value from the arraylist when you need it.  What are you actually trying to acccomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the number of differences between each combination of strings in my `ArrayList` and put those in a 2d array. For example `s1 = AAA` `s2 = ABA` `s3 = ABC` `s1s2 = 1` `s1s3 = 2` `s2s3 = 1` and then put those values into a difference matrix. I guess I can just compare the values as I fill the matrix based on i and j since [0][0] would be s1s1 [0][1] would be s1s2 ect. I just didn't know if there was an easier way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot. This is what arrays (and `ArrayList`s) are for!